# use array to define name of methods within a class

Tags: arrays, class, methods

I would like to name the methods with an array like this

```
class MyClass {
    private $_array = array();
    public function __construct($array) {
        $this->_array = $array; //this works!
    }

    //now, what i'm trying to do is:
    foreach ($this->_array AS $methodName) {
        public function $methodName.() {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

when you working with classes and want something like dynamic methods - i think  the magic method __call is the best way.

you can make it very easily:

```
class MyClass {
    private $_array = array();
    public function __construct($array) {
        $this->_array = $array; //this works!
    }


  public function __call($method, $args) {
      if(in_array($method, $this->_array)){
              print "Method $method called\n"; 
          //or you can make like this:  return call_user_func_array($method, $args);
      }
  }

}

$obj = new MyClass(array("one","two"));

$obj->two();  // OUTPUT: Method two called
```